# pickDate: false is not working in datetimepicker bootsrap?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, datetimepicker

Why is `pickDate: false` not working in datetimepicker bootstrap?

HTML

```
<input type="text" class="form-control input-small evstime" name="evstime" readonly="readonly" />
```

JS

```
$(function() {
    $('.evstime').datetimepicker({
      pickDate: false 
    });
});
```

Comment: What do you mean by `not working`? What are trying to do with this option?

Answer (score 1):

Are you using this http://tarruda.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/#disables_date_picker?

HTML

```
<div class="input-append datetimepicker">
    <input type="text" data-format="hh:mm:ss" class="evstime" name="evstime"/>
    <span class="add-on">
        <i data-time-icon="icon-time"></i>
    </span>
</div>
```

JS

```
$(function() {
    $('.datetimepicker').datetimepicker({
      pickDate: false 
    });
});
```

Check out this js fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/zxhgnq9b/